# Regex detection for Puppet configuration

Tags: ruby, regex, configuration

I've got a PR to add a feature to a Ruby application (Puppet) to allow Regex detection.

Right now, the method only does comparison on exact string matching:

```
defaultfor :operatingsystem => :fedora, :operatingsystemmajrelease => ['22', '23', '24']
```

This is annoying, as we have to add in new values everytime a new Fedora release comes out, for example.

I've extended it to match on a Regex:

```
defaultfor :operatingsystem => :fedora, :operatingsystemmajrelease => /^2[2-9]$/
```

The old method looks like this:

```
def self.fact_match(fact, values)
  values = [values] unless values.is_a? Array
  values.map! { |v| v.to_s.downcase.intern }

  if fval = Facter.value(fact).to_s and fval != ""
    fval = fval.to_s.downcase.intern

    values.include?(fval)
  else
    false
  end
end
```

This is my current proof-of-concept code, which will match both regex and strings, but it feels off.

```
def self.fact_match(fact, values)

  values = [values] unless values.is_a? Array

  values.map! do |v|
    if v.is_a? Regexp
      v
    else
      v.to_s.downcase.intern
    end
  end

  if fval = Facter.value(fact).to_s and fval != ""
    fval = fval.to_s.downcase.intern
    if values.any? {|v| v.is_a? Regexp }
      regex_match = Regexp.union(values)
      fval =~ regex_match
    else
      values.include?(fval)
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I feel like there's a much easier way of detecting if it's a Regex or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working too hard, trying to distinguish strings from regular expressions.  Rather, you should take advantage of the fact that the [`===` operator for a `RegExp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) and the [`===` operator for a `String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) both express the idea of a "match", which is what you want here.

I don't understand why you need to `#intern` all the strings.

I don't see why the `fval = Facter.value(fact).to_s` assignment appears inside an `if` condition.  The result of the assignment would only be `false` if `Facter.value(fact).to_s` is `false` or `nil`, which can never happen.  (Even `nil.to_s` results in an empty string.)

To treat `values` as an array regardless of whether a scalar or an array was passed in, you can use the `[*values]` idiom.

```
def self.fact_match(fact, values)
  fact_val = Facter.value(fact).to_s.downcase
  fact_val != "" and [*values].any? { |v| v === fact_val }
end
```

In addition to supporting literal case-insensitive matches and regular expression matches, also consider supporting `Range`s.

Comment: That's a lot cleaner, thanks! Makes a lot more sense.

Looking at the commit for that code, it looks like that extra intern logic was added when each defaultfor became a hash of multiple different values. 

Indeed, when I change the logic to the code given, everything works ok except for the unit tests for multiple defaultfor values... I'll have to investigate deeper!

Comment: I'm gladyou answered with the `===` idiom.  It's one of my favorites.  Also, the `[*values]` idiom can also be expressed as `Array(values)`